# Should I use "WLAN" or "Wi-Fi" to refer to wireless LAN?

Tags: discussion, questions

Pretty much when WLAN connectivity became widespread, we were referring to wireless LAN as "WLAN". But for whatever reason, people began to refer to it as "Wi-Fi" which to me, is just the certificate that the "WiFi Alliance" puts onto devices. In other words, it still feels kinda *recent* that people started using the term "WiFi" to me.

I still find it a little difficult to refer to that as "WiFi", because we're talking about WLAN devices in my mind. I'm unsure if this causes for confusion, though. Should I refrain from using WLAN and use WiFi instead, when responding to questions?

Comment: Are you asking about tags or about the body of your answers?

Comment: My main reason for using "wifi" is that "WLAN" is too easy to mix up with "VLAN". But you may do as you wish.

Comment: @terdon body of answers. It seems the tags /wlan and /wifi are synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

Long before it got to the point where I felt the need to ask this question, I would probably have just started calling it "wifi". Much like when the world suddenly decided we were calling asynchronous Javascript "AJAX", and "SQL" suddenly became a word instead of three letters. I really don't care what you call it, but "wifi" is pretty much ubiquitous, whereas I'm not sure I've ever heard "WLAN" before now

Comment: OK, I'll try to force myself using "WiFi", then... Also, "SQL" is "ess-que-ell" and not "sequel" in my book.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, *Wi-Fi* stands in the marketing lingo for the standard [IEEE_802.11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11). That's why the name is met on router labels, most likely with a specifier added like *802.11b* or *802.11g*. So *in its strict meaning* this term denotes a [physical layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_layer) standard, as seen in the [OSI Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model).

As for *WLAN*, it denotes a [Local Area Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network), which uses [wireless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless) or (another name) [radio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_frequency) interfaces as the [physical layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_layer) in the [OSI Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), though not necessarily exclusively. So a *WLAN* is a *LAN*, but the name indicates a radio access way is present.

The difference is then one between *an area network* vs *a protocol group*. The contrast becomes sharper when you compare both terms against *[Wireless WAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_WAN)* or *WWAN* for short. Here the physical radio layer part has many faces, not just Wi-Fi.

It is then intuitively clear to me that as far as *strictness* is concerned, *WLAN* is a more appropriate name for *Wireless LAN* than *Wi-Fi*. The latter, however, can be used to denote *WLAN* in its (*Wi-Fi*'s) figurative, [metonymous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) sense, which is far from precision, but is more popular.